# Get User Data from Facebook API 2.4 in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using below code to fetch User data from `Facebook`. But, recently `facebook` have updated `API` Version and after that it is returning only ID and Name, not other information like Email, Photo, Birthdate etc.
Please help me how do i get all needed information ?

```
FaceBookConnect.Authorize("email", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]);

string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
FacebookUser faceBookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FacebookUser>(data);
```

Comment: why down vote ? let me know if i have written anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use:

https://graph.facebook.com/2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,currency

> Note : The field 'email' is only accessible on the User object after
>   the user grants the 'email' permission.

Comment: what modification, i will need to do in my coding ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,gender");
```